# Multiple selection of dropbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a project where i have to select multiple options in drop down and that number of text boxes should appear with that selected label. i.e in drop down i have 4 options in drop down i have countries name like India, America, china and i want to select multiple options so i press shift and click multiple options, in this case i press America and china so i want 2 text boxes to be created automatically with text in it of that country name.

**Work i have done**:
i have done on click work like when user click button that times text boxes are created. that is the work that i have done in the paste. please help me how to do that

Comment: What have you attempted so far? You are already (assuming by your choices of tags) understanding that you need JavaScript and maybe a library like jQuery to back it up. But have you tried anything thus far that isn't working? If so, please edit your post and share the code. We are all developers here, don't be shy, we've seen code big and small.. :-D

Comment: Is the problem the multiple select or the JavaScript part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this markup:

```
<div id="cont1">

    <select id="sel1" name="sel1" multiple>
        <option value="First">First</option>
        <option value="Second">Second</option>
        <option value="Third">Third</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

this script should get you started:

```
$(function() {

    $('#sel1 option').on('click', function(e){

        if($(this).is(':selected')){
            $('<input value="'+$(this).val()+'" />').appendTo('#cont1');
        }

    });

});
```

In order to actually use the values in, say, a PHP script, you'd need to add names to each input; otherwise, the form fields don't get submitted with the form. Also, note that this syntax does assume you're using jQuery 1.7+.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ajax by following this tutorial

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant to the question; the OP doesn't need to send anything to the server, but rather edit the existing HTML.

Comment: yet this may also be his answer to his problem.. like he said he is will use it in his project so i thought it would use database and sending through server